# Configure Tor Browser to use a private Bridge

Tags: configuration, bridge

I want to configure my Tor Browsers to use a private Bridge but cannot locate any documentation which gives the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the documentation that you are looking for:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges

> ## Understanding A Bridge Configuration Line
>
> As an example, when you obtain a bridge from https://bridges.torproject.org, you'll get a bridge entry that looks like the following:
>
> - 141.201.27.48:443 4352e58420e68f5e40bf7c74faddccd9d1349413
>
> Understanding the components of a bridge line isn't strictly required but may prove useful. You can skip this section if you'd like.
>   The first element is the IP address of the bridge: '141.201.27.48'
>   The second element is the port number: '443'
>   The third element, the fingerprint (unique identifier of the bridge), is optional: '4352e58420e68f5e40bf7c74faddccd9d1349413'

Now you need to edit it as you need.
How to add this line in TBB is written here:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#AddTorNotWorks

Comment: Much appreciated, I'll see if I can take it from here...